# How do I change the spacing (between lines/paragraphs) in my mobile footer - css? Code below is from responsive.css wordpress

Tags: css

How do I change the spacing (between lines/paragraphs) in my mobile footer - css? Code below is from responsive.css wordpress

this is from the responsive.css part of my wordpress

I want the spacing to be closer than what it is currently - you can check it by visiting www.hotdatajobs.digitalya.ro

```
/* new changes footer */
    @media ( max-width: 640px ) {
        .col-xs-12.p-t-20.padding-l-r-10 span {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .site-footer {
            padding-top: 40px;
        }
        .footerRow .col-md-15.col-sm-15.col-xs-12 .title-block {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .m-h-f {
            min-height: 295px;
        }
        .m-h-l {
            min-height: 170px;
        }
    }

    @media ( max-width: 440px ) {

        .m-h-f,
        .m-h-l {
            min-height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .m-h-f {
            min-height: 230px;
        }

        .p-l-f {
            width: 150px!important;
        }

        .site-footer .footerRow .footer-social-item {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .site-footer .footerRow a {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .col-xs-12.p-t-20.padding-l-r-10 span,
        .site-footer .title-block {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }

    @media ( max-width: 374px ) {

        .m-h-f,
        .m-h-l {
            min-height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .m-h-f {
            min-height: 225px;
        }

        .p-l-f {
            width: 110px!important;
        }

        .footerRow .col-xs-12 {
            padding: 0;
        }
        .site-footer .footerRow .footer-social-item {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .site-footer .footerRow a {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .col-xs-12.p-t-20.padding-l-r-10 span,
        .site-footer .title-block {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    }
    /* end general */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control spacing between lines of texts with the line-height property.

For example, 16px font-size and 4px distant from the bottom and upper lines:

```
line-height: 24px; /* 4px +16px + 4px */
```

Or with em units

```
line-height: 2em; /* 1em = 12px in this case. 24/12 == 2  */
```

So..

```
.site-footer .footerRow .footer-social-item {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

Of course, increasing of decreasing the line-height depending on how much spacing you want. Anything below 16px will cut off your text because you are using 16px text so keep that in mind.

Also keep in mind that when the width of that div gets greater than 440px the line-height value will not apply.

Comment: thanks! being that I'm not technical, could you edit my code please? cuz when i am trying to it, it's not working